# AccessViolationException in Delphi - impossible (check it, unbelievable...)

Tags: delphi, error-handling, access-violation

Delphi XE. Windows 7.

There is a function (please see a code below) or `I:=0` that causes an AV error in a big project. There is no the error with the same function in a new project!!! I deleted everything from the big project, and I left only a button and that function. It still causes the error...

A line with the error:

```
if ISAeroEnabled then // this line is a cause
       i:=0;         // or this line
```

I set breakpoints everywhere (I checked the whole function, I set breakpoints on **EACH LINE** -> no errors in the function), a debugger shows me that the error is in `i:=0;`

If to delete a function (and leave `i:=0;`) -> **all is ok!**

The error message: `First chance exception at $747FB727. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 004AE5AF in module 'MngProject.exe'. Write of address 0017FFF8'. Process MngProject.exe (4980)`

Why does it work in a new project but not in mine?

Here's the whole project: http://www.2shared.com/file/UP22Om4j/Bug.html

The code:

```
unit MainFormModule;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  StdCtrls;
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public

    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
     mainform:tmainform;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}

function  ISAeroEnabled: Boolean;
type
  _DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc = function(IsEnabled: PBoolean): HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Flag                       : Boolean;
  DllHandle                  : THandle;
  OsVersion                  : TOSVersionInfo;
  DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc: _DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc;
begin
  Result:=False;
  ZeroMemory(@OsVersion, SizeOf(OsVersion));
  OsVersion.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVERSIONINFO);

  if ((GetVersionEx(OsVersion)) and (OsVersion.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and (OsVersion.dwMajorVersion >= 6)) then //is Vista or Win7?
  begin
    DllHandle := LoadLibrary('dwmapi.dll');
    if DllHandle <> 0 then
    begin
      @DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'DwmIsCompositionEnabled');
      if (@DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc <> nil) then
      begin
        DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc(@Flag);
        Result:=Flag;
      end;
    end;
      FreeLibrary(DllHandle);
  end;
end;

procedure Tmainform.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
begin
    if ISAeroEnabled then // AV is here
       i:=0;              // Or here
end;
end.
```

Comment: Come on... You've asked enough questions now to know that you need to provide specific information. What *exactly* is the access violation error message? Have you stepped into the `IsAeroEnabled` function in the debugger? What Windows version? What line is causing the access violation? Set a breakpoint at the start of `IsAeroEnabled`, run your app, and single-step until you know which line is causing the problem. Then edit your question, mark the line that's causing the AV, and add the **exact** error message from that AV. Otherwise, I'll be down-voting this question and voting to close it.

Comment: @Ken White, Edited. And as I sad, a strange thing that it works in a new project, not in mine. Please check mine, I've uploaded it.

Comment: Your edit didn't really help. As I said, post the **exact** error message from the access violation. Also, follow my instructions about using the debugger above - set a breakpoint on the *first line of `IsAeroEnabled` and run until the breakpoint is triggered, and then step through the code line by line (using F8) until you get the AV, and mark that line in the code above. Last chance to fix it, I'm afraid - if you won't follow simple instructions to help track it down, it's not worth putting effort into trying to help you. You have 79 questions here, and had problems providing info in most.

Comment: I've done everything  what you sad (I cannot understand what else to do if I checked all code with break points :( ) except an error message, I've posted it too.

Comment: Set the breakpoint in your **REAL** project (the one that has the actual problem). Set it on the line with `ZeroMemory` in `IsAeroEnabled`. Run it til the breakpoint is hit, then press F8 on each line until the access violation happens. Tell us what line that happens on. How hard is that to understand (for the **third** time)????

Comment: I've done it as you sad!!!!!  I checked the whole function with breakpoints - I set them on EACH line -> no errors. I wrote it :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try changing `PBoolean` to `PBOOL`

```
function(IsEnabled: PBOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;

var
  Flag: BOOL;
```

PBoolean is a pointer to a Pascal Boolean which is 1 byte in size. PBOOL is a pointer to a Windows (C based) BOOL, which is 4 bytes in size. You need to match the size expected by windows.

In general, when translating Windows API calls to Delphi, use the same named data type as the API. Windows.pas has type definitions mapping these to Delphi types, e.g. `type BOOL = LongBool;`

Also it is usual (but not required) in Delphi to change pointer parameters to var. A var parameter is Pascal syntactic sugar for pass-by-reference which isn't available in C.

```
function(var IsEnabled: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
....
    DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc(Flag); // no @ operator
```

**NOTE:** I can't test this, as I only have XP available.

Comment: Gerry, exactly, thanks a lot!!! I really didn't know what to do. That function works fine in a new project but why not in mine I couldn't imagine. Again, thanks!!! For me (Windows 7, Delphi XE) it works nice!

Comment: @maxfax - it worked in a new project through luck. You were passing a pointer to a single byte to a function that expected 4 bytes. This lead to some of your stack being overwritten, with unpredictable results. Also note the call to GetVersionEx(OsVersion)) is unnecessary, as this information is already loaded by the Delphi RTL into SysUtils.Win32Platform, Win32MajorVersion and Win32MinorVersion.

Comment: `In general, when translating Windows API calls to Delphi, use the same named data type as the API. Windows.pas has type definitions mapping these to Delphi types, e.g. type BOOL = LongBool;` This is **so true**. I keep on repeating that too.

Comment: When a very simple instruction (Like `I := 0`) crash... it has the smell of buffer overflow all over it... Godo catch on the PBoolean vs PBOOL.

Comment: @Ken - that's why I looked up the function definition on MSDN