# How to determine programmatically the Windows' Performance settings with Delphi 2010

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

The following code is to fade my application on close.

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnClose1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 255 downto 0 do begin
    frmMain.AlphaBlendValue := i;
    application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

  Close;
end;
```

With Windows performance set to “Let Windows choose…”

- When closing my Delphi app with the above code the fade is almost
  instantaneous (maybe ¼ second at the most, if I blink I miss the
  transition).

If I set the performance Option to ‘Adjust for best performance”

- When exiting the same app the fade takes over 12 seconds.
- Using the same code but commenting out the AlphaBlendValue change removes the delay.

I tested this out on both Delphi 2010 and DelphiXE2 and the results are the same.
This was tested on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit if that makes any difference.

To say the least this behavior puzzles me.

- I thought that the forms Alpha property was handled by the GPU and would therefore not be affected by Windows performance settings that should would be targeted at maximizing CPU performance.

So as far as this is concerned I'm not sure if this is a Windows 7 bug, a Delphi bug  or just my lack of knowledge.

As far as a fix...
Is there a way to tell if Windows is running in crap graphics/max performance mode so that I can disable Alpha fade effects in my apps?

---

Edit for clarity:
While I would like to fix the fade what I am really looking for is a way to determine what the Windows performance setting is.

I am looking for how to determine a specific Windows setting - when you go into Windows Performance Options there are 3 tabs. On the first tab "Visual Effects" there are 3 canned options and a 4th option for 'Custom'. Minimally I am trying to determine if the option chosen is 'Adjust for best performance', if I could determine what the settings are on this tab even better.

---

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental problem with your code is that you are forcing 256 distinct updates irrespective of the performance characteristics of the machine. You don't have to use every single alpha blend value between 255 and 0. You can skip some values and still have a smooth fade.

You need to account for the actual graphics performance of the machine. Since you cannot predict that, you should account for real time in your fade code. Doing so will give you a consistent rate of fade irrespective of the performance characteristics of your machine.

So, here's a simple example to demonstrate tying the fade rate to real time:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnClose1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  NewAlphaBlendValue: Integer;
begin
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  while True do
  begin
    NewAlphaBlendValue := 255-(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds div 4);
    if NewAlphaBlendValue>0 then
      AlphaBlendValue := NewAlphaBlendValue
    else
      break;
  end;
  Close;
end;
```

The fade has a 1 second duration. You can readily adjust the mathematics to modify the duration to your requirements. This code will produce a smooth fade even on your low performing machine.

I would also comment that you should not use the global variable `drmMain` in a `TfrmMain` method. The `TfrmMain` method already has access to the instance. It is `Self`. And of course you can omit the `Self`. What's more the call to `ProcessMessages` is bad. That allows re-entrant handling of queued input messages. You don't want that to happen. So remove the call to `ProcessMessages`.

---

You actually ask about detecting the *Adjust for best performance* setting. But I think that's the wrong question. For a start you should fix your fade code so that the fade duration is independent of graphics performance.

Having done that you may still wish to disable the fade if the user has asked for lower quality appearance settings. I don't think you should look for one of the 3 canned options that you mention. They are quite possibly Windows version specific. Personally I would base the behaviour on the *Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing* setting. My rationale is that if the user does not want minimize and maximize to be animated, then presumably they don't want window close to be faded.

Here's how to read that setting:

```
function GetWindowAnimation: Boolean;
var
  AnimationInfo: TAnimationInfo;
begin
  AnimationInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(AnimationInfo);
  if not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETANIMATION, AnimationInfo.cbSize,
      @AnimationInfo, 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := AnimationInfo.iMinAnimate<>0;
end;
```

I think that most of the other settings that you may be concerned with can also be read using [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx). You should be able to work out how to do so by following the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't  Windows have its native API for windows animation ?

Comment: The timing comments are valid if I want to have a fade. If I knew that the user's system was 'optimized' in the fashion mentioned then I would skip fading entirely because it would always look bad.  The  'performance' setting is stored somewhere or derived the question is how to determine it.

Comment: The code in my answer will give a nice fade on your troublesome machine. Try it and see. Your code does 255 separate updates and that takes 12 seconds on the awkward machine. That's 20 updates per second. That will give a very nice fade.

Comment: @Arioch'The there is `AnimateWindow()` which supports fading

Comment: My code example was a simplified & derived. The app was already partially faded to AlphaBlend value of 150 by the OnCloseQuery() code asking 'Do you really want to close?' and then took an additional 12 seconds to close after that. My mistake for lack of clarity. I will give your suggestion a try and check it out. But still would like to be able to determine the answer to the original question and still surprised that the Windows' setting would affect the alphablend so negatively.

Comment: I'd be astounded if you could get a reliable prediction for how the machine will perform when given code like this. There are just so many factors involved. The only reliable way is to time it, which is what my answer describes.

Comment: @AlexK. Do you know how to use `AnimateWindow(..., AW_BLEND)` in a VCL app?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan nope, no idea, I just knew its the win32 that can do it.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but you're not understanding what I am asking. I am not trying to predict Windows performance, I am looking for how to determine a specific Windows setting - when you go into Windows Performance Options there are 3 tabs. On the first tab "Visual Effects" there are 3 canned options and a 4th option for 'Custom'. Minimally I am trying to determine if the option chosen is 'Adjust for best performance', if I could determine what the settings are on this tab even better.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what you are asking. I'm just telling you that you are asking the wrong question. You've just found one of the many ways for a machine to have slow graphics performance. There are countless more. I'm offering a solution to all of those problems. So, no I didn't answer the specific question you asked and won't. I don't know the answer. Just wait. No doubt somebody else will answer the question you asked. I just think my solution is better.

Comment: I just ran your code on my machine with "Adjust for best performance". The fade took half a second. Can you explain that?

Comment: >>I just think my solution is better<< for this example cited it very well might be (I will try your solution for the fade timing in the morning). But I am just as concerned with other issues that this particular setting might cause that I will probably find later. I would also like to capture what the performance settings are for my bug reports.

Comment: >>I just ran your code on my machine with "Adjust for best performance". The fade took half a second. Can you explain that? << (What are you running? would have come off less aggressive) Both my customer and I are running Windows 7 64bit (I'm running Ultimate, don't remember if he is). We both have NVidia graphic cards. So maybe your system is setup differently?

Comment: Actually probably the difference could be that my form was very simple. Didn't mean to be aggressive. Was a rhetorical question pointing out that it's hard to explain and predict perf differences. Have edited my answer to be more balanced. Fixing fade is no. 1 priority. Then you can refine that by disabling fade if user has requestion no animations. That's the bit I don't (yet) have an answer for.

Comment: @TheSteven OK, have a look at my very latest update. I think I've got all the bases covered now!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21292/discussion-between-thesteven-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Where acb I get TStopWatch for Delphi 2010?

Comment: It's in the Diagnostics unit. You can find that online by searching. Start here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Main_Page

Comment: Found a working solution - posted answer with code. See post for details.

Comment: @TheSteven What you have posted doesn't answer the question that you asked. Nowhere in the question did you ask about DWM composition.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the tardy followup but it took me a while to figure out a working answer to my question and some of the issues behind it.

First, a thank you to David Heffernan for insight on a better way to handle the fade loop and information on the TStopWatch function from the Delphi's Diagnostics unit, much appreciated.

In regards to being able to determine the Windows' Performance settings...

When using the following un-optimized fade loop

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnFadeNCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 255 downto 0 do 
    frmMain.AlphaBlendValue := i;

  Close;
end;
```

the actual **Windows Performance Option** settings causing the performance issue are  "***Enable desktop composition***" and "***Use visual styles on Windows and buttons***". If both options are enabled there is no issue, if either setting is not enabled the loop crawls** (about 12 seconds on my system if the form is maximized).

Turns out that turning **Aero Glass** on or off affects these same 2 settings. So being able to detect if Aero Glass is on or not enables me to determine whether to not to enable the form effects, such as transition fades and other eye candy, in my apps. Plus now I can also capture that information in my bug reports.

> **Note this appears to be an NVidia issue/bug, or at least an issue that is much more severe on systems with NVidia graphics cards. On 2
>   different NVidia systems (with recent, if not latest drivers) I 
>   got similar results for a miximized form fade - less than
>   .001 seconds if Aero Glass is on, around 12 seconds if Aero Glass is
>   off. On a system with an Intel graphics card - less than .001 seconds
>   if Aero Glass is on, about 3.7 seconds if Aero Glass is off. Now
>   granted my test sampling is small, 3 NVidia systems (counting my
>   customer who initially reported the issue) and one non-NVidia system
>   but if I was using a decent NVidia graphic card I would not bother
>   turning Aero Glass off.

Below is the working code to detect if Aero Glass is enabled via Delphi:
This function has been tested on a Windows7 64 bit system and works with Delphi 2007, 2010 and Xe2 (32 & 64bit).
All of the various versions of the Delphi function below that I found on the net were broken - along with comments of people complaining about getting Access Violation errors. 
What finally shed the light on fixing the bad code was Gerry Coll's response to: [AccessViolationException in Delphi - impossible (check it, unbelievable...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198646/accessviolationexception-in-delphi-impossible-check-it-unbelievable) which was about trying to fix AV errors in a function of the same type.

```
function  ISAeroEnabled: Boolean;
type
  _DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc = function(var IsEnabled: Bool): HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  Flag                       : BOOL;
  DllHandle                  : THandle;
  OsVersion                  : TOSVersionInfo;
  DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc: _DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc;
begin
  Result:=False;
  ZeroMemory(@OsVersion, SizeOf(OsVersion));
  OsVersion.dwOSVersionInfoSize := SizeOf(TOSVERSIONINFO);

  if ((GetVersionEx(OsVersion)) and (OsVersion.dwPlatformId = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) and
      (OsVersion.dwMajorVersion = 6) and (OsVersion.dwMinorVersion < 2)) then //Vista&Win7 only (no Win8)
  begin
    DllHandle := LoadLibrary('dwmapi.dll');
    try
      if DllHandle <> 0 then
      begin
        @DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'DwmIsCompositionEnabled');
        if (@DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc <> nil) then
        begin
          if DwmIsCompositionEnabledFunc(Flag)= S_OK then
           Result:= Flag;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FreeLibrary(DllHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Should be `OsVersion.dwMajorVersion = 6`. Also must easier to read it out of `TOSVersion.Major` and `TOSVersion.Minor`. What's more the function you have written is needless. Use `Dwmapi.DwmCompositionEnabled`.

Comment: Your function is also somewhat odd in the way it tries to exclude Windows 8. I don't understand that. Basically I don't think this answers the question you asked, and it's a very misleading piece of code.

Comment: It intentionally excludes Windows 8 because only Vista & Windows 7 support Aero Glass.

Comment: >>Should be OsVersion.dwMajorVersion = 6.<< Your are right, corrected code.

Comment: Edit: >>It intentionally excludes Windows 8 because only Vista & Windows 7 support Aero Glass.<< Actually there is Aero Glass in Win 8 but you cannot turn it off, it is always on.  Link to one of many discussions on Win 8/Aero Glass: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1095937-hey-look-aero-is-not-gone-in-windows-8-rtm/

Comment: The version check shouldn't be in that function. And for that function you can simply call the RTL function that comes with Delphi. But it's still not related to the question that you asked. You asked about reading perf settings. And you were adamant that was what you wanted to do. Now, checkin if composition is enabled is quite probably a very sensible way to get the information that you really need. But it isn't what you asked for. And in comments to my answer you objected strongly when I tried to steer you to a different solution. No, you were adamant that you had to read the perf settings.

Comment: The performance options settings that affected graphic performance turned out to be 2 particular settings, mentioned previously, that together support Aero Glass; so I disagree.

Comment: You did make me realize that to do what I originally stated the function should be rewritten as IsAeroDisabled() and return True if Aero Glass has been disabled on an operating system that supports it.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to persuade you to step back and think more boadly and with an open mind to different solutions. You were adamant that you need to read the perf settings. Read the comments again.

Comment: I completely agree that reading the true underlying property that controls the behaviour is a good approach, but it's not how you asked the question. I still don't understand why my answer isn't accepted. The thing about SO is that it's about specific questions and answers to those problems. You didn't ask about graphic performance. You asked very clearly and directly how to read a particular user setting.

Comment: As for the function in your answer, why don't you call the one built in to Dwmapi?

Comment: >>As for the function in your answer, why don't you call the one built in to Dwmapi?<< Wasn't aware of till now of the Dwmapi unit that comes with Delphi 2010 & higher, thanks for the info!